# What is a good resource for learning how to illustrate maps?

Tags: illustration, maps

I'm trying to create an illustrated map for a friend's wedding. Most map tutorials I can find are for technical maps and I would like to find a resource with tips and tricks for designing more illustrative, design maps. Examples below:
[image] [image]

Answer (score 4):

These are all hand drawn/painted. You won't really find many tutorials on how to draw something as specific as a map. Just look for general drawing tutorials.

It's honestly just a matter of picking up a pencil and start drawing it.

There are no magic buttons or tutorials to draw something for you.

Answer (score 4):

While seconding Scott's "There's no magic button," what I did when I had to create city and country maps was to find an actual paper map, scan it, and trace it in Illustrator. That gave me a good realistic grid. From there I could simplify the map, pretty it up, tweak streets, add icons, etc.

If you want the hand-drawn look, buy the paper map and use tracing paper or a lightbox so you can trace the original.

Answer (score -1):

This tutorial from Smashing Magazine seems relevant:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/illustrated-maps-in-era-of-google-earth/

Comment: Link only answers are usualy not a good idea for several reasons.

Comment: Hi user61893, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!